# What properties can be said for a subset of the reals which has a Lebesgue measure strictly greater than zero?

Tags: lebesgue-measure

What properties can be said for a subset of the reals which has a Lebesgue measure strictly greater than zero?

I tried googling but there weren't that many and if there was they were poorly explained

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the measure of $E$ is greater than $0$ then $E$ has the cardinality of $\mathbb{R}$. This is because the set $E+E$ contains an interval and $|E+E| = |E|$. This answer uses the axiom of choice.

Comment: An easier way of showing this is to assume for the sake of contradiction that $E$ is countable, and prove from there that $E$ has measure 0.

Comment: Suppose that $|\mathbb{R}| > { \aleph}_{1}$ and $|E| = {\aleph}_{1}$?

Comment: Fair point. Instead my comment shows $E$ is uncountable while your answer proves a stronger statement.